# how can I search/filter through JSON strings that are saved in MySQL DB

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with the columns id, journalName and archive, where archive stores JSON string in the form

```
"[\"Text 1\",\"Text 2\",\"Text 3\",\"Text 4\"]"
```

I am trying to come up with a function which can search or filter through each item in the JSON string from each row returned from a query. The results returned was to contain the matching Text(s) grouped by the corresponding journalName.

I have tried several options with the current attempt being

```
        public function search(Request $request)
        {
                $archives = Archive::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                $search = $request->input('search');                    
            
            $filteredResults = $archives->filter(function ($item) use ($search) {
                $decodedArchive = $this->decodeArchive($item->archive);
                return $this->arrayContainsText($decodedArchive, $search);
            });
        
            $groupedResults = $filteredResults->groupBy([
                'journalName',
                function ($item) {
                    return $item->created_at->toDateString();
                }
            ])->map(function ($group) {
                return $group->pluck('archive');
            });
        }


        private function arrayContainsText($array, $search)
        {
            foreach ($array as $item) {
                if (stripos($item, $search) !== false) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But have been unsuccessful. How may I accomplish this?

Comment: What version of mysql do you have? More recent ones include native JSON functions. Alternatively, consider normalising your data

Comment: Hi @ADyson,  I am using version 5.5. It came with Xampp 8.1.12. I had tried code with JSON functions like JSON_CONTAINS and JSON_EXTRACT but kept getting empty results with valid searches or it would return all the text instead of the matching text. There is a possibility I was using them wrong but cant tell since no errors were generated

Comment: MySQL 5.5 is horribly outdated, it has seen it's last updates in 2018. Also, it would probably be easier to refactor your database for a more normalized design, such that both searches and updates are easier

Comment: COrrection @ADyson, I was looking at another config. I installed lampp which uses MariaDB 10.4.27

Comment: If your archive column has a proper JSON data type, then you should be able to do this simply using https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: you can use JSON_CONTAINS method to search in the column

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to do it. I'll give examples as sample not based on your structure. You can make it up for your own structure.

First one is run raw query:

```
$query = DB::table('your_table')
       ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(your_json_column, ?)', ['"Text 1"'])
       ->get();
```

Please note that in the JSON string in the whereRaw() clause, "Text 1" must be enclosed in double quotes because JSON strings must be enclosed in double quotes.

Second option is using `whereJsonContains`:

```
$query = DB::table('your_table')
           ->whereJsonContains('your_json_column', "Text 1")
           ->get();
```

**Important:** Keep in mind that for the JSON functions to work properly, the JSON column should have a json type in your MySQL database schema. If the column type is text or varchar, you might run into some issues.

Please be aware that it is not recommended using json search for complex json structure. Because searching through JSON data can be slower than using standard SQL queries on appropriately indexed columns, especially when dealing with large amounts of data. JSON search queries cannot take full advantage of SQL's indexing capabilities, which can lead to inefficient queries. However for your case, structure is simple I think it will not affect performance much. you need to be careful when your data is getting bigger.